# How to upload files on s3 Bucket in Background Task uisng PHP WordPress?

Tags: uploads, wp-cron

I have a website where users upload their videos. Videos length is more than 600 MB so I want to run videos upload in background and update in database. Users will also be notified via email. So cron job will take care of it once database is updated.

I want to respond user that you will be notified via email once video is uploaded. So he can browse my website or can upload new video. Video uploading will be running in background. A little guide or any solution will be appreciated.

This is my AJAX Request

```
 myform.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const videoFile = document.getElementById("product-video");
        const selectedFile = videoFile.files[0];

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('fileToUpload', selectedFile);
        formData.append('action', "handle_file_upload");
        console.log("AJAX request Started");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response + " Sucesses");
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.error("Error is: " + error);
            }
        }); '''


Here is How I handle it.

''' function handle_file_upload() {
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    set_time_limit(0);
    if (!empty($_FILES['fileToUpload'])) {

        $bucket = 'yachtingimage';
        $keyname = 'product-video' . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] . uniqid();
        $filename = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
    
        $s3 = new S3Client([
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region'  => 'us-east-1',
            'credentials' => [
                'key' => 'AKIAJXQ2ZGDLFS6XN6QQ',
                'secret' => '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',
            ],
        ]);
        
        $result = $s3->createMultipartUpload([
            'Bucket'       => $bucket,
            'Key'          => $keyname,
            'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
            'Metadata'     => [
                'param1' => 'value 1',
                'param2' => 'value 2',
                'param3' => 'value 3'
            ]
        ]);
    
        $uploadId = $result['UploadId'];
    
        try {
            $file = fopen($filename, 'r');
            $partNumber = 1;
            while (!feof($file)) {
                $result = $s3->uploadPart([
                    'Bucket'     => $bucket,
                    'Key'        => $keyname,
                    'UploadId'   => $uploadId,
                    'PartNumber' => $partNumber,
                    'Body'       => fread($file, 5 * 1024 * 1024),
                ]);
                $parts['Parts'][$partNumber] = [
                    'PartNumber' => $partNumber,
                    'ETag' => $result['ETag'],
                ];
                $partNumber++;
            }
            fclose($file);
        } catch (S3Exception $e) {
            $result = $s3->abortMultipartUpload([
                'Bucket'   => $bucket,
                'Key'      => $keyname,
                'UploadId' => $uploadId
            ]);
        
            echo "Upload of {$filename} failed.";
        }
        
        $result = $s3->completeMultipartUpload([
            'Bucket'   => $bucket,
            'Key'      => $keyname,
            'UploadId' => $uploadId,
            'MultipartUpload'    => $parts,
        ]);
        $url = $result['Location'];
        echo "Uploaded {$filename} to {$url} ";
    } else {
        echo "File was not uploaded";
    }
    die();
}
```